# oracle SQL: stats_crosstab chi square test returning 0

Tags: sql, oracle, chi-squared

I am performing the following query (simplified):

```
SELECT STATS_CROSSTAB(Person, Category, 'CHISQ_DF') DF,
STATS_CROSSTAB(Person, Category, 'CHISQ_OBS') CHI_SQUARED, 
STATS_CROSSTAB(Person, Category, 'CHISQ_SIG') CHI_SIG 
FROM
tbl
```

where tbl is

```
Person  Category    Count
Person1 Category1   7
Person1 Category2   1
Person1 Category3   1
Person1 Category4   39
Person2 Category1   6
Person2 Category2   2
Person2 Category3   1
Person2 Category4   35
Person3 Category1   7
Person3 Category2   1
Person3 Category3   1
Person3 Category4   14
```

This is the result I am getting:
DF: 6 (which is correct)
CHI_SQUARED: 0 (which is not correct)
CHI_SIG: 1     (which is not correct)

I calculated the result manually and the answer should be:
DF: 6 (which is correct)
CHI_SQUARED: 4.5 (which is not correct)
CHI_SIG: 0.87     (which is not correct)

What is causing the problem? I know from another example that this should be possible.

Comment: The roundness of the values of `CHI_SQUARED` and `CHI_SIG` seem suspicious. What client are you using? For what it's worth, when I ran STATS_CROSSTAB() on your sample data I got `6,  8.98294755, 0.174539362`.

Comment: @APC I am using oracle sql developer. I'm surprised that you are getting at least an answer. 6 should be correct (I made a small error with that), but 4.5 should be correct.

Comment: You seem to think that the counts are taken into account. They are not. You are calling the function on the columns Person and Category; the Count column is completely ignored. If you want to get the proper statistics, you need to repeat each row "Count" times. (You can do that in a subquery - I will show how in an Answer.)

Comment: By the way, 4.5 is approximately right, but 0.87 is not. How did you calculate those numbers manually? (Actually... not sure it's relevant...)

Comment: I think the 0.87 was also calculated with 9 degrees of freedom instead of 6! I had to adjust the data because of confidentiality and excluded some data, causing the DF to be different. I will adjust this.

Comment: @mathguy You are right that is the problem.

Comment: I got results because I assumed the `count` column was the output of an aggregation and inserted the number of records indicated. I should have been more literal, like @mathguy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why your query is not working: You seem to think that the counts are taken into account. They are not. You are calling the function on the columns `Person` and `Category`; the `Count` column is completely ignored.

If you want to get the proper statistics, you need to repeat each row "Count" times. You can do that in a subquery. How to make it work:

```
with tbl ( Person, Category, cnt ) as (
       select 'Person1', 'Category1',  7 from dual union all
       select 'Person1', 'Category2',  1 from dual union all
       select 'Person1', 'Category3',  1 from dual union all
       select 'Person1', 'Category4', 39 from dual union all
       select 'Person2', 'Category1',  6 from dual union all
       select 'Person2', 'Category2',  2 from dual union all
       select 'Person2', 'Category3',  1 from dual union all
       select 'Person2', 'Category4', 35 from dual union all
       select 'Person3', 'Category1',  7 from dual union all
       select 'Person3', 'Category2',  1 from dual union all
       select 'Person3', 'Category3',  1 from dual union all
       select 'Person3', 'Category4', 14 from dual
     )
SELECT STATS_CROSSTAB(Person, Category, 'CHISQ_DF') DF,
STATS_CROSSTAB(Person, Category, 'CHISQ_OBS') CHI_SQUARED, 
STATS_CROSSTAB(Person, Category, 'CHISQ_SIG') CHI_SIG 
FROM
(select person, category
   from tbl
 connect by level <= cnt
        and prior person = person
        and prior category = category
        and prior sys_guid() is not null
);

DF                                CHI_SQUARE              CHI_SIG
--  ----------------------------------------  -------------------
 6  4.55259268824609733700642791551882460974  0.60233419532255972
```

Comment: In this table the count is always greater than 0, but what if this is not the case (e.g. person 2, category 1, 0).

Comment: @SvenCozijn - that is a separate question which has nothing to do with `stats_crosstab`. It can be done in several ways; if you need help, post a separate question on this site. (You can reference this post, but the question is really different.)